# How do i enable EER Model in MYSQL 6.3 workbench ? or How can i create foreign key for my "offers" table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, workbench

These are my tables users and offers

---

### users

name   username   email   password   authority   enabled

---

### offers

id   text

But i want to create a foreign key in my offers table from the column name "username" in my users table. How do i do it with my sql workbench 6.3 ? or how do i enable EER model for my tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are create statement for the two tables.

**offer** table

```
CREATE TABLE `offer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `username_id_idx` (`username_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `username_id` FOREIGN KEY (`username_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`iduser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**user** table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `iduser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authority` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If you are using Workbench 6.3 you can check the EER diagram by : 
Database - > Reverse Engineer - > Select a connection - > Select the scheme you want to see.

[image]

Hope this helps!